# Good jQuery Employee Scheduler

Tags: jquery

I am looking for something similar to this image.  It should allow me to add as many employees as I want, within reason, and schedule fixed periods (30min etc) against them.  I had a Google and can only find calendars, which is not what I am looking for.

Thanks.

[image: jQuery Time Scheduler]

Comment: bit too localized really....need to code it up yourself, or pay for it!

Comment: This seems to be [off-topic for Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), what've you tried already? Have you attempted to program/script this yourself?

Comment: I am not really a client-side programmer so my jQuery/JavaScript skills are lacking seriously for this kind of application.  As for it being off-topic, I am sorry but I just figured that there are amazing programmers on here which might have used something like this.

Comment: Psst: [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) gets you close, and there's an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=150) about implementing this exact functionality.  Perhaps you could contribute to the project?

Comment: @josh3736 Thanks a million.  The source for that project seems fairly straight forward to me and since there is a requirement I will give it my best shot.